# How to render a list of objects properly in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to create the Snake game in Elm. What I have so far is a model of the snake, an update function and a view function.

In the update function I cut off the last part of the snake and add a new part as its head.

However, when rendering the snake it collapses all its parts (circles) to one circle. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
import Playground exposing (..)

type alias Position = 
  { x : Number
  , y : Number
  }

type alias SnakePart = 
  { position : Position
  }

type alias Snake = List SnakePart 

updateSnakePart : SnakePart -> Computer -> SnakePart

updateSnakePart ({ position } as snakePart) computer = 
    if computer.keyboard.up then 
      { snakePart | position = { position | y = position.y + 40 } }
    else if computer.keyboard.down then 
      { snakePart | position = { position | y = position.y - 40 } }
    else if computer.keyboard.left then 
      { snakePart | position = { position | x = position.x - 40 } }
    else if computer.keyboard.right then 
      { snakePart | position = { position | x = position.x + 40 } }
    else
      snakePart

updateSnake : Computer -> Snake -> Snake

updateSnake computer snake = let 
                                snakeHeadMaybe = List.head snake
                              in
                                case snakeHeadMaybe of
                                  Nothing -> []
                                  Just snakeHead ->
                                    updateSnakePart snakeHead computer :: List.take (List.length snake - 1) snake

initialSnake = 
  [ { position = { x = 0, y = 0 } }
  , { position = { x = 40, y = 0 } }
  , { position = { x = 80, y = 0 } }
  ]

main =
  game view updateSnake initialSnake 

view computer snake =
  List.map (\snakePart -> circle blue 20 |> move snakePart.position.x snakePart.position.y) snake
```

**EDIT**

Direction of the snake now baked into the game state. Now, however, it just go in one direction and doesn't seem to react to the arrow keys.

```
import Playground exposing (..)

type alias Position = 
  { x : Number
  , y : Number
  }

type Direction = Up | Down | Left | Right

type alias SnakePart = 
  { position : Position
  }
  
type alias Snake = List SnakePart 

type alias Game = 
  { snake: Snake
  , direction: Direction
  }

updateSnakePart : SnakePart -> Direction -> SnakePart

updateSnakePart ({ position } as snakePart) direction = 
  case direction of
    Up -> { snakePart | position = { position | y = position.y + 40 } }
    Down -> { snakePart | position = { position | y = position.y - 40 } }
    Left -> { snakePart | position = { position | x = position.x - 40 } }
    Right -> { snakePart | position = { position | x = position.x + 40 } }

updateDirection direction computer = 
  if computer.keyboard.up then 
    Up
  else if computer.keyboard.down then 
    Down
  else if computer.keyboard.left then 
    Left
  else if computer.keyboard.right then 
    Right
  else
    direction

updateGame : Computer -> Game -> Game

updateGame computer game = 
  let 
    snake = game.snake
    snakeHeadMaybe = List.head snake
    direction = updateDirection game.direction computer
  in
    case snakeHeadMaybe of
      Nothing -> { snake = [], direction = Up }
      Just snakeHead ->
        { snake = updateSnakePart snakeHead direction :: List.take (List.length snake - 1) snake
        , direction = direction
        }

initialGame = 
  { snake = 
    [ { position = { x = 0, y = 0 } }
    , { position = { x = 40, y = 0 } }
    , { position = { x = 80, y = 0 } }
    ]
   , direction = Up
  }
    
  
main =
  game view updateGame initialGame 

view computer game =
  List.map (\snakePart -> circle blue 20 |> move snakePart.position.x snakePart.position.y) game.snake
```

What is wrong with the code? Also, is there a way to slow down the update frequency?

Comment: Your rendering function is actually fine. What's happening is that `updateSnake` is happening 60 times per second no matter what, and when you aren't pressing any arrow keys, `updateSnakePart` places the new head on top of the old one (because of its final `else snakePart` branch). Maybe you can add the direction the snake's head is moving in to the game state, and make the arrow keys update that state.

Comment: I added direction to the game state (see edits) but now it doesn't seem to respond to the arrow key presses.

Comment: My bad; the key arrows actually works as intended with the second solution in which the direction is included in the model.